# Check if the given string has duplicates

Tags: java, strings, interview-questions

**Description:**

Given a string find if it contains duplicate characters. The string contains only `ASCII` characters.

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  /**
   * Given a string check if it duplicate characters.
   * []        -> true
   * [f, o, o] -> false
   * [b, a, r] -> true
   * 
   * @param {String} str
   * 
   * @return false if string contains duplicate else true
   */ 
  public static boolean isUnique(String str) {
    if (str.length() == 0) {
      return true;
    }
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int index = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i)) - 'a';
      if (seen[index]) {
        return false;
      }
      else {
        seen[index] = true;
      }
    }
    // invariant
    return true;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isUnique(""));       // true
    System.out.println(isUnique("a"));      // true
    System.out.println(isUnique("foo"));    // false
    System.out.println(isUnique("bar"));    // true
    System.out.println(isUnique("hello"));  // false
    System.out.println(isUnique("Hello"));  // false
  }
}
```

The above algorithms runs in `O(n)`, the alternate solution is to sort the string and the check the adjacent elements but it would be `O(nlogn)`. I need to understand if I am using Java correctly, any other styles related comments are most welcome.

PS: I would like to know if I need to include more tests to cover all cases.

Comment: how about null argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Documentation mismatch

The documentation and the functionality do not fit. Your function is supposed to "check if [a string] has duplicates". From the documentation, I expect a function `hasDuplicates` that returns `true` if I have duplicate characters and `false` otherwise.

However, you provide `isUnique`, which does the opposite: return `true` if there are *no* duplicates and `false` if there *are* duplicates. The internal documentation fits, but I would say "checks whether it contains **no** duplicate characters" or "contains unique characters only".

## Possible bugs

You checked your string only on alphabetic strings. What happens on `"12345678"`? You will index `-48` due to `'1' - 'a'`. That's a bug waiting to happen. Also, what happens if your string contains a `'z'`? What happens if `str` is `null`? Maybe `str` shouldn't be `null`, but that should get mentioned in the documentation (see above).

Also, you should mention that your function is case-insensitive. But why does `"Aa"` count as a duplicate to begin with?

Both cases (non-alpha character and same letters in different cases) should get added to your tests.

## Algorithm

Your `seen` algorithm is fine if you know exactly how many buckets you need. But you often don't know that. A `Map<char,bool>` can happen here. If you use a `TreeMap` you end up with the mentioned \$\mathcal O(n \log n)\$, but if you use a `HashMap` the asymptotic complexity is \$\mathcal O(n)\$ again. Alternatively, use a set.

But that's *asymptotic* complexity. If you don't consider any non-alpha strings (see section above), then you can immediately return `false` if the string is longer than `26` characters due to the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: I don't know much about `TreeMap` and I will read about it more. I checked reference book and it says that we can assume `ASCII` letters including digits i.e. all `256` characters. If I have to I would prefer `Set` than map.

The author also suggests that we could use bit vector too but the solution seem too complex to me.

Comment: @CodeYogi I should add that I don't know much Java. I can read and understand almost all of it, but I don't know the standard library well, for example, so I had my C++ glasses on. If you know that all characters are ASCII values then `boolean[256]` is fine and most likely the easiest and cache friendliest method.

Answer (score 1):

- There are considerably more than 25 ASCII characters. Did you mean ASCII *letters*? Cause if the test was for *characters*, this code will break. But even if it's just letters, (case aside,) there are 26 letters, not 25. Try adding "pizza" and "crazy" to your test, and see what happens. :P

  The quick and dirty solution is to make your array 26 elements long.

  A better solution, though, might be to use a `HashSet<Character>` rather than an array of booleans. While a bit slower, it also removes the limitation of "only ASCII letters". Use it a lot like your array: for each character, if it's already in the set, return `false`; otherwise add it.
- Your tests don't include cases like, say, "America" (where upper and lower case appear in the same word). They should.
- Speaking of tests, you might consider using an actual testing framework of some kind. `System.out.println` lets you see something's being returned, which is good for just starting out...but something like `Test.assertFalse(isUnique("pizza"))` would let you run the test even if you didn't remember what it was supposed to do.

Comment: Good explanation but I am preparing for an interview and I fear there will be any test framework available in editor.